# Generics and usage of interfaces without boxing of value instances

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-optimization, jit

As I understand, generics is an elegant solution to resolve issues with extra boxing/unboxing procedures which occur within generic collections like `List`. But I cannot understand how generics can fix problems with using interfaces within a generic function. In other words, if I want to pass a value instance which implements an interface of a generic method, will boxing be performed? How does the compiler treat such cases?

As I understand, in order to use the interface method the value instance should be boxed, because a call of a "virtual" function requires "private" information contained within the reference object (it's contained within all reference objects (it also has a synch block))

That's why I decided to analyze the `IL` code of a simple program to see if any boxing operations are used within the generic function:

```
public class main_class
{
    public interface INum<a> { a add(a other); }
    public struct MyInt : INum<MyInt>
    {
        public MyInt(int _my_int) { Num = _my_int; }
        public MyInt add(MyInt other) => new MyInt(Num + other.Num);
        public int Num { get; }
    }

    public static a add<a>(a lhs, a rhs) where a : INum<a> => lhs.add(rhs);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(add(new MyInt(1), new MyInt(2)).Num);
    }
}
```

I thought that `add(new MyInt(1), new MyInt(2))` will use boxing operations because the add generic method uses the `INum<a>` interface (otherwise how can compiler emit virtual method call of value instance without boxing??). But I was very surprised. Here is a piece of `IL` code of `Main`:

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
IL_0001: newobj instance void main_class/MyInt::.ctor(int32)
IL_0006: ldc.i4.2
IL_0007: newobj instance void main_class/MyInt::.ctor(int32)
IL_000c: call !!0 main_class::'add'<valuetype main_class/MyInt>(!!0, !!0)
IL_0011: stloc.0
```

Such listing does not have `box` instructions. It seems like `newobj` does not create a value instance on heap, for values it creates them on stack. Here is a description from documentation:

> (ECMA-335 standard (Common Language 
>   Infrastructure) III.4.21) Value types are not usually created using newobj. They are usually allocated either as arguments 
>   or local variables, using newarr (for zero-based, one-dimensional arrays), or as fields of objects. 
>   Once allocated, they are initialized using initobj. However, the newobj instruction can be used to 
>   create a new instance of a value type on the stack, that can then be passed as an argument, stored 
>   in a local, etc.

So, I decided to check out the `add` function. It's very interesting, because it does not containt box instructions either:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
!!a 'add'<(class main_class/INum`1<!!a>) a> (
    !!a lhs,
    !!a rhs
) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 15 (0xf)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarga.s lhs
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: constrained. !!a
    IL_0009: callvirt instance !0 class main_class/INum`1<!!a>::'add'(!0)
    IL_000e: ret
} // end of method main_class::'add'
```

What's wrong with my assumptions? Can generics invoke virtual methods of values without boxing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, anyway, invoking of interface methods (I guess) should rely on the same principles as virtual methods. On something like tables of virtual functions

Comment: You make it sound like generics were primarily introduced to address boxing issues. Yes, there are benefits there, but adding parametric polymorphism to the language was the *goal*.

Comment: `constrained.` takes care of turning `callvirt` into a non-virtual `call` if the argument is a value type, and also of boxing the value if absolutely necessary (when you call a non-overridden method of `Object`, `ValueType` or `Enum`, which is not the case here). In your first example, you'll also note `call` is being used to invoke the method directly rather than through the interface -- the compiler can do this because it knows the exact type. If you want to see boxing, try something like `INum<MyInt> x = new MyInt(1); MyInt y = new MyInt(2); x.add(y);`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Your comment is misleading. All methods which implement interface members are required by the CLR to be virtual. If you do not have virtual, override or abstract in your C# source code, the compiler does special tricks to make a virtual version of the method behind the scenes.

Comment: @EricLippert removed it. I assumed the OP's code, description were correct. Hard to think or (remember to) research while trying to find what''s responsible for missing records in a database ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> As I understand, generics is an elegant solution to resolve issues with extra boxing/unboxing procedures which occur within generic collections like `List<T>`.

Eliminating boxing was a by-design scenario for generics, yes. But as Damien points out in a comment, the more general feature was enabling more concise, more type-safe code.

> if I want to pass a value instance which implements an interface of a generic method, will boxing be performed?

Sometimes, yes. But since boxing is expensive, the CLR looks for ways to avoid it.

> I thought that `add(new MyInt(1), new MyInt(2))` will use boxing operations because the add generic method uses the `INum<a>` interface

I see why you made that deduction, but it is wrong.  How the body of the method you called *uses* the information is irrelevant.  The question is: what is the *signature* of the method you are calling?  C# type inference determines that you are calling `add<MyInt>`, and therefore the signature is equivalent to calling:

```
public static MyInt add(MyInt lhs, MyInt rhs)
```

Now, you rightly point out that there is a constraint. The C# compiler verifies the constraint is met, which it is.  **That does not change the calling convention of the method**.  The method takes two `MyInt`s, and you've passed it two `MyInt`s, and they are value types, so they are passed by value.

> It seems like newobj does not create a value instance on heap, for values it creates them on stack.

Make sure that this is clear: it creates them on the *abstract evaluation stack of the IL program*.  Whether the jitter turns that code into code that puts the values on the actual stack of the current thread is an implementation detail of the jitter. It could choose to put them in registers, for example, or into a data structure that has the logical properties of a stack, but is actually stored on the heap, or whatever.

> `add` does not contain box instructions either

Yes it does, you just aren't seeing them. It contains a constrained callvirt which is a conditional box.

constrained callvirt has the semantics:

- there must be a reference to the receiver on the stack. There is: `ldarga` puts the address of the receiver on the stack. If the receiver is a reference type, the address of the variable containing the reference will be on the stack. If it is a value type, then the address of the variable that holds the value type will be on the stack. (Again, this is the stack of the virtual machine we are reasoning about here.)
- the arguments must be on the stack. They are; the argument to `INum<MyInt>.add` is a `MyInt`, and again, that is passed by value, and the value is on the stack from the `ldarg`.
- if the receiver is a reference type, we then dereference the double-reference we just created to get the reference and the virtual call happens normally. (Of course, the jitter is free to optimize away this double-reference!  Remember, all these semantics I am describing are of the virtual machine of the IL program, not of the real machine you're running it on!)
- if the receiver is a value type and the value type implements the method you're calling, then the value type's method is called normally: that is, without boxing the value.  **This is the case your example is in**, so we avoid boxing.
- if the receiver is a value type that does not implement the method you're calling, then the value type is boxed, and the method is called with a reference to the box as the receiver. **Exercise to the reader:** Create a program that falls into this case.

> What's wrong with my assumptions?

You've assumed that calls to methods on value types via interfaces must box the receiver, but that's not true.

> Can generics invoke virtual methods of values without boxing?

Yes.

Comment: You are right, I missed out `.constrained` prefix. It fully clarifies mechanics. Maybe it'll help for somebody. It's description at ECMA-335 standard (Common Language Infrastructure) III.2.1

Comment: I understand, it's kind of optimization.But  Can JIT potentially inline  method of value? Of course, if receiver is value type and it implements method